# EBNF or BNF for the LOGO programming language

Tags: bnf, ebnf, logo-lang

Does anyone know where I can get the BNF or EBNF for the [LOGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29) programming language?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close this as off-topic. "Programming language" is even in the title...

Comment: It appears this made its way to Reddit, I'm protecting this for now (will be unprotected in a few days). It's not a problem, _yet_, just a precaution.

Comment: @Tim Post This made it to the reddit programming subreddit, I fail to see how this is cause for alarm. Might have even been a good opportunity to attract new users?

Comment: Off topic? Well played, mods. Voting to reopen.

Comment: How is a question about EBNF's and BNF's off-topic?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A BNF grammar might not be too useful in certain circumstances...

Writing a LOGO that's accurately compatible with existing/historical implementation isn't an easy task (I worked on such a project). The problem is that the parser doesn't do the full job, and the evaluator (interpreter) has to work with partial data. Consider this example:

*proc1 a b proc2 c*

It could mean proc1(a, b, proc2(c)) or proc1(a, b, proc2(), c) according to the number of parameters for proc1 & proc2.

Furthermore the LOGO interpreters I know, for example Berkely LOGO, seem from a cursory glance not to write a traditional parser that additionally has access to each procedure and its arity; instead they run the procedures and the procedures 'eat up' the number of parameters that they need. This makes the parser a little naive and the main role is that of an interpreter, and thus parsing is kind of unusual.

Comment: So are you saying that there cannot be a grammar for the language that is unambiguous?

Comment: Yes, I think no such grammar exists (regardless of ambiguity) unless it's a naive grammar that parses the command string mostly as-is, and just resolves infix operators and the like

Comment: Right, a naive parser would just parse according to the grammar, but it wouldn't understand the *arity* of built-in functions. It would seem that while parsing, one would need to look up the *arity* of the function before deciding how to parse the succeeding tokens. It also makes more sense then as you said, to "parse as you go".

Comment: "Parse as you go" is the way my own logo implementation [Logo Arabic](http://code.google.com/p/logoarabic/) does it. I haven't really studied the LOGO implementation scene, and the parser itself is ad-hoc, so I don't claim my work is best practice or even good practice; but the source might be useful for your work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm definitely going to take a look at it!

Comment: @VivinPaliath, one particularly bad one is the minus sign (i.e. the `-` in `-52`). When you parse you save your words (minus is a "word") in a list. When you print a list, you write spaces between words EXCEPT the minus sign because if you add a space after the minus it becomes a DIFFERENCE (i.e. `33 -52` is different from `33 - 52`). For numbers you are likely to convert the value immediately. However that's very important when you write `-:A`. In this case you want the opposite of `:A`...

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard LOGO implementation.

Your best call is probably to look at the source of a popular implementation, such as [UCBLogo](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html)